# Why do the Western European countries use the AZERTY keyboard? What is the historical origin of this layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, country

Most countries in the world use the QWERTY keyboard. The Central and Eastern European countries: Germany, Austria, Liechtenstein, Switzerland, Hungary,  Poland, Slovenia, Czech Republic, Slovakia, Croatia, Estonia, Latvia, Lithuania, Moldova, Belarus, Ukraine, and the Russian Federation use the QWERTZ keyboard only because their languages use "Z" more often than "Y". However, I noticed that the Western European countries: France, Monaco, Belgium, and Luxembourg use the AZERTY keyboard with the letter "M" in the middle row instead of the bottom row. Great Britain and the Netherlands could also potentially use the AZERTY keyboard.

My questions are:

1. How did the keyboard layouts develop historically? Was there a practical reason to have these keyboard layouts?
2. Why haven't these countries reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard? Italy also used the QZERTY keyboard with the letter M in the middle row. At least Italy has reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the QZERTY keyboard.

Comment: Your question answers itself: it's to do with letter frequency.

Comment: What's going on with your edit history? What do the UNCTAD, IUCN, FATF, "rosicrucian countries", or ITU have to do with your question exactly? Are you trying to describe which countries you're talking about? Because it would be **much** clearer for you to just name them. I would posit that most people could not name the member countries for each of those groups, much less even know what those acronyms stand for.

Comment: "_reformed this redundancy_" I've only had one, very limited, experience of an AZERTY keyboard, but as far as I can remember, there's no _redundancy_ involved. The letters may be in difference places, but I'm pretty sure none were duplicated.

Comment: Interestingly, French-speaking Quebec uses the QWERTY layout. I find this layout for the French language better than the AZERTY one. The Quebec layout is better thought out in my opinion as it also lets one use a capital É and put diacritics on other capital letters, including Ç. The AZERTY keyboard does not allow for this.

Comment: @PeterWebb And even French-speaking Haiti and French Guiana  do not use the AZERTY keyboard either.

Comment: Why would Monaco and Vatican City be significantly different than the already provided general answer?

Comment: @Ángel Because my question text has been quoted in the answer. We are only trying to handle the quotations.

Comment: I mean why you [updated](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/134513/revisions) the question 2 years later to add those two countries there.

Comment: I covered the answer update in the comment there, in that I don't see Vatican City using AZERTY.

Comment: @Ángel Look at the original version of my question. I initially only had France and Belgium. And the original version of the answer was quoted accordingly. "Why haven't France and Belgium reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard?". I later added Luxembourg, so then also I had to make a suggested edit to update this quotation. It is only this quotation which matters.

Comment: @Ángel Sorry for the ping, but as the OP of the answer, what do you think of the latest text in this question ? had previously proposed a suggested edit after adding Monaco and Vatican City, but you rejected the edit. So, my final consideration in the question is simply "Why haven't these countries reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard?". The bounty to the question is almost expiring, and this text is still pending review.  I want to know your opinion as the OP. I just want a straight answer. Thanks.

Comment: _You_ would be the OP (Original Poster), not me. You keep doing changes to the question, but I find it to be significantly the same. I agree with the removal of Vatican City, which is unlikley to be using AZERTY. I don't think Spain, Portugal or the Netherlands would use AZERTY. These are mainly historical traction. They _could_ use AZERTY, like any other layout. In fact, you can easily configure a different layout at your OS, independently to what the keyboard has printed.

Comment: @Ángel It is not the list of countries that matters now. My question text simply says "Why haven't these countries reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard?" without the explicit list of countries. That quotation is what needs to be updated in the answer.

Comment: @Ángel I have now posted at https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/not-satisfied-with-original-formulation-of-my-question-and-the-answers-i-receive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How did the keyboard layouts develop historically?

Did you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#History and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY ?

In the beginning, there was not *a* keyboard layout. Each keyboard manufacturer had one. In fact, early Sholes typewriters had the keys arranged alphabetically. Trying to solve a jamming problem (and probably also based on letters frequency and users' feedback) is how the initial QWERTY layout was born. The success of the Remington No. 2 of 1878 made this very popular.

AZERTY (just like [QWERTZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ) or [QZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#QZERTY)) is basically a QWERTY variation adapted for a given language (based on the assumption that it would be better to type a given language if certain letters that are very frequent on them appear on the home row).

> Why haven't these countries reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard?

Why should they use QWERTY? Do note that it isn't an optimal keyboard layout, either. Why aren't you -I assume- using QWERTY and not DVORAK?

There are lots and lots of users that learnt to type in AZERTY. There would be an high cost of changing to a different layout. Plus, there are lots and lots of physical keyboards in those places showing an AZERTY layout.

There is a cost of switching to something else. In fact, a [BEPO layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%89PO) would be preferable from a theoretical point of view. However, it would be costly for users to retrain themselves into a different layout. And with most computers in the country using AZERTY, that would put them in a disadvantage when using a different computer. This makes them to continue using AZERTY. Just like other countries continue using QWERTY.

Note: there was recently a keyboard layout standardization by French AFNOR (NF Z71‐300), but it kept the position of AZERTY letters, see https://norme-azerty.fr/ (there was an accompanying BEPO layout, too)

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya what makes you think Vatican City significantly uses an AZERTY layout?

Comment: Please see my latest edit to the question. My question text now reads as "Why haven't these countries reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard." The quotation should also be updated.

Comment: I have temporarily unaccepted this answer because I am frustrated that three times I have made edits to the question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1803702/has-the-system-requirement-for-windows-11-on-a-dell-xps-13-9310-laptop-changed-s, but the question is not getting reopened.